# How to find all occurrences of a list of strings in a string and return a list of list of int in python?

Tags: python, string, list

For example

```
def find_all_occurrences(a,b):
'''
>>>find_all_occurrences('wswwswwwswwwws', ['ws', 'wws'])
[[0,3,7,12], [2,6,11]]
'''
```

How can I return a list of lists that have all the occurrences without import any modules.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions

```
import re
def all_occurrences(a, b):
    return [[occur.start() for occur in re.finditer(word, a)] for word in b]
```

Without imports it gets a little messy, but definitely still doable

```
def all_occurrences(a, b):
    result = []
    for word in b:
        word_res = []
        index = a.find(word)
        while index != -1:
           word_res.append(index)
           index = a.find(word, index+1)
        result.append(word_res)
    return result
```

Comment: OP requested no imports.

Comment: @wwii noted. Edit made

Comment: I test it and at line 5 it says, TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

Comment: @CrystalTran Should be `a.find(word)` my bad

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the occurrences by using the last found position as the start of the next search:

> ```
> str.find(...)
> S.find(sub [,start [,end]]) -> int
>
> Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found,
> such that sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional
> arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.
>
> Return -1 on failure.
> ```

A loop that calls `haystack.find(needle, last_pos + 1)` repeatedly until it returns -1 should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can also have simple list comprehensions to help with problems like these

```
[[i for i in range(len(a)-len(strng)+1) if strng == a[i:i+len(strng)]] for strng in b]
```

where

```
>>> a
'wswwswwwswwwws'
>>> b
['ws', 'wws']
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with a recursive procedure.  I used a *nested/inner* function to maintain the OP's function signature:

```
def find_all_occurrences(a,b):
    '''
    >>>find_all_occurrences('wswwswwwswwwws', ['ws', 'wws'])
    [[0,3,7,12], [2,6,11]]

    '''
    def r(a, b, count = 0, result = None):
        if not a:
            return result
        if result is None:
            # one sublist for each item in b
            result = [[] for _ in b]
        for i, thing in enumerate(b):
            if a.startswith(thing):
                result[i].append(count)
        return r(a[1:], b, count = count + 1, result = result)
    return r(a, b)
```